# How to get Model Choice Field name instead of id in template using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting id of choice field in the template.But I want name of the choice field to display. Please review the below files and let me know how to get the name.

here is my models.py

===============================================================

```
class Posted(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Posted In'),max_length=255, unique=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Tag Name'),max_length=255, unique=True)

class Blogs(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    posted=models.ForeignKey(Posted, blank=True)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializers.py

---

```
class BlogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Blogs
        fields = ('id','author','title','tags','posted','content','created_at','updated_at')
        read_only_fields=('id','created_at','updated_at')

class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()   
    class Meta:
        model = Tags 
        fields = ('id','name')
        read_only_fields=('id','name')
class PostedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Posted
        fields = ('id','name')
        read_only_fields=('id','name')
```

views.py

---

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Blogs.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class= BlogsSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)
        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(),IsAuthorOfBlog(),)

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

        return super(BlogViewSet,self).perform_create(serializer)

class TagsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Tags.objects.all
    serializer_class= TagsSerializer

class PostedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Posted.objects.all
    serializer_class= PostedSerializer
```

## Template

## ```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="blog">
        <div class="blog__meta">
          <a href="#">
            +{{ blog.author.first_name }}
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog__content">
          <p>{{ blog.title }}</p>
          <p>{{ blog.posted}}</p>
          <p>{{ blog.tags}}</p>
          <p>{{ blog.content }}</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @ Karol Sztajerwald.
Yes BlogsSerializer has to be made like that.

Finally Blogs Serializer.py is

```
class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tags

        fields = ('id','name')
        read_only_fields=('id','name')

class PostedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Posted

        fields = ('id','name')
        read_only_fields=('id','name')
class BlogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True,required=False)
    tags=TagsSerializer(many=True)
    posted=PostedSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Blogs

        fields = ('id','author','title','tags','posted','content','created_at','updated_at')
        read_only_fields=('id','created_at','updated_at')
```

template is

```
<p>{{ blog.title }}</p>
<p>{{ blog.posted.name}}</p>
<p>{{ blog.tags.name}}</p>
<p>{{ blog.content }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) option to return a specific field as a relation object. For example,

```
class BlogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True,required=False)
tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    slug_field='name'
 )
class Meta:
    model = Blogs
    fields = ('id','author','title','tags','posted','content','created_at','updated_at')
    read_only_fields=('id','created_at','updated_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by choices ? I see no `choices` in Field kwargs. You can set Choice field by for example:
`chairs = models.IntegerField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES)` and where exactly you get id's instead of name ?

Comment: Choices are from two tables. Posted and tags .modelchoicefields

Comment: I recreated your env, and here is what I accomplished:
In your `BlogsSerializer` add your serializers and that gives you proper json output:
```class BlogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posted = PostedSerializer()
    tags = TagsSerializer(many=True)
```
Note that because Tags is many to many relation, we need to pass kwarg `many=True` and also as a future tip - try to use singular names for models in your case it will be `Blog`, `Tag` etc.